# Узнать прокси на клиенте

Tags: c#, wcf

У меня сервер использует контракты обратного вызова для связи с клиентом. Но как мне на клиенте в обработчике функции этого контракта узнать прокси сервера для ответа ему? Можно ли как то? Я имею ввиду не просто хранить подключенный, а как то динамически узнать, т.к. я хочу сделать чтобы клиент мог быть подключен одновременно к нескольким серверам. Прокси серверов (объекты контрактов) хранятся в списке, но как мне из обработчика контракта обратного вызова узнать с какого сервера пришло сообщение, чтобы отправить ему ответ?

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?

Comment: Все еще жду ответа!!! :(

Comment: @Manushin Igor что именно не понятно? Я вроде старался объяснить насколько возможно понятно...

Comment: извиняюсь, отправилось.

Непонятен вопрос... WCF всегда держит горячее tcp соединение. Callback - это просто отправка данных по уже готовому каналу.
Если используется proxy (socks, http, https), то во всех случаях всё будет работать без каких-то доработок.
Если Вы подписались на кучу сервисов, и вопрос в том, как в методе разделять их, то могу привести пример кода..

Comment: @Manushin Igor именно так. Последний вариант. Я хочу подписаться на несколько сервисов сразу. Их прокси-объекты хранятся в списке. Но я не знаю какой из них вызвал обработчик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как разделить callback-методы сервисов:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IMyContractCallback
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void OnCallback();
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyContractCallback))]
    public interface IMyContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoSomething();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
    public class MyService : IMyContract
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi from server!");
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallback>();
            callback.OnCallback();
        }
    }

    public class MyContractClient : DuplexClientBase<IMyContract>
    {
        public MyContractClient(object callbackInstance, Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
            : base(callbackInstance, binding, remoteAddress)
        { }
    }

    public class MyCallbackClient : IMyContractCallback
    {
        private readonly string _clientIdentity;

        public MyCallbackClient(string clientIdentity)
        {
            _clientIdentity = clientIdentity;
        }

        public void OnCallback()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi from client {0}!", _clientIdentity);
        }
    }
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var uri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost");
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof (MyService), uri))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyContract), binding, "");
                host.Open();

                using (var client = CreateClient(binding, uri, "1"))
                {
                    using (var client2 = CreateClient(binding, uri, "2"))
                    {
                        var proxy2 = client2.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                        proxy2.DoSomething();
                    }

                    var proxy = client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                    proxy.DoSomething();
                }
            }
        }

        private static MyContractClient CreateClient(NetTcpBinding binding, Uri uri, string clientIdentity)
        {
            var callback = new MyCallbackClient(clientIdentity);
            var client = new MyContractClient(callback, binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));

            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

Напечатается два ответа от сервиса. К сожалению, для каждого proxy необходим новый client factory (в моем решении).

Comment: Зачем вы, создав client, тут же берете у него фабрику и создаете канал?.. Client - это ведь уже канал, надо только реализовать в нем нужные методы (или позволить автогенератору кода сделать это).

Comment: А если хочется использовать фабрику напрямую - так и надо создавать сразу ее, а не клиента.

Comment: @Manushin Igor в итоге я так и не увидел решения... Где у вас подключение клиента к нескольким сервисам? Нету...

Comment: @DarkByte вот тут у него назначение: `var callback = new MyCallbackClient(clientIdentity);`

Comment: @DarkByte разумеется, вместо строки можно передать что угодно

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov но это совсем не то про что я спрашивал! Я говорю о том что клиент подключается к нескольким сервисам сразу. (одинаковым, но на разных конечных точках) У него этого нет.

Comment: @DarkByte есть, посмотрите как создаются `client` и `client2`. Им можно разные uri передать.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov да зачем мне два клиента??? Мне нужно чтобы один и тот же клиент подключался к нескольким сервисам!!! Создается калбэк, подключаются обработчики, создается инстанс, создается и подключается прокси и добавляется в список. Потом сервис вызывает калбэк и на клиенте срабатывает обработчик. Из этого обработчика надо выяснить какой сервис из списка вызвал обработчик.

Comment: @DarkByte один клиент в WCF **никогда** не сможет подключиться к разным сервисам!

Comment: @DarkByte не нервничайте, расслабьтесь, и перечитайте свое же сообщение еще раз. Именно так все в этом ответе и работает, разве что подключение обработчиков не показано.

Comment: Ааа все я понял. Че то тупанул немного. Но все равно где у него именно список прокси и определение с какого прокси был вызов???

Comment: @DarkByte списка у него нет, у него показано как создавать каналы - ну а собрать их в список нетрудно. Здесь показано как можно пометить колбек строкой. Вам этого недостаточно чтобы найти нужный прокси в списке?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov понимаете я реализую свой калбэк немного не так как он. Я добавляю туда события, которые вызываются из функций калбэка и подписываюсь на них. А из события я этот его идентификатор никак не получу...

Comment: @DarkByte ну так передавайте его в обработчик событий...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov хорошо, допустим это вариант. С текстом он сработает, но мне нужен не текстовый идентификатор, а сам прокси-объект. А как я передам прокси-объект в калбэк, если если он создается уже после создания калбэка и это сам калбэк передается в конструктор прокси.

Comment: @DarkByte Тогда не в конструктор его передавайте, а сделайте открытое свойство, которое можно будет заполнить уже после создания прокси-объекта.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov думаю это сработает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант без создания лишних клиентов и с событиями:

Интерфейсы и сервис (для примера):

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallback))]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Hello();
}

interface ICallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void CallbackHello();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class Service : IService
{
    public async void Hello()
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        callback.CallbackHello();
    }
}
```

Класс клиента. Здесь мне пришлось пойти на хак и переопределить часть стандартной реализации - потому что `DuplexClientBase`, внезапно, создает новую фабрику на каждый новый инстанс обратного вызова - а создание фабрики все-таки дорогая операция.

Важно! Этот класс нарушает [`LSP`](https://habrahabr.ru/post/83269/), то есть этот класс лучше не передавать коду, который ожидает базовый класс. Также желательно не обращаться к его унаследованным открытым свойствам. Вообще, по-хорошему надо было бы писать свой клиент с нуля - но мне лень.

```
class ServiceClient : ClientBase<IService>, ICallback
{
    private readonly DuplexChannelFactory<IService> factory; // Общая для клиентов фабрика

    public EndpointAddress Address { get; private set; } // Информация для подключения (пример)

    public ServiceClient(DuplexChannelFactory<IService> factory, EndpointAddress address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    protected override IService CreateChannel()
    {
        return factory.CreateChannel(new InstanceContext(this), Address);
    }

    public new ChannelFactory<IService> ChannelFactory
    {
        get { return factory; }
    }

    // Пример запроса к сервису
    public void Hello()
    {
        base.Channel.Hello();
    }

    // Пример события обратного вызова
    // Как и просили - в нем указывается сам клиент первым параметром.
    public delegate void CallbackHelloDelegate(ServiceClient client);
    public event CallbackHelloDelegate CallbackHello;
    void ICallback.CallbackHello()
    {
        var h = CallbackHello;
        if (h != null) h(this);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
    var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(typeof(ServiceClient), "client");

    foreach (var i in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }) // Три клиента - для примера
    {
        var client = new ServiceClient(factory, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/TestService")); // Адрес забит константой - но вам, наверное, надо его как-то вычислять
        client.CallbackHello += client_CallbackHello;
        client.Hello();

        // Положить клиент в список, я думаю, вы и сами сможете
    }
```